# Foreign primary key inserting (increment issue)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
CREATE TABLE Accounts
(ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY);


CREATE TABLE Students
( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , s_name VARCHAR(20) ,date_birth DATEtime,age AS (YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(date_birth)) , school_id INTEGER ,
FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES Accounts(ID) ,
FOREIGN KEY(school_id) REFERENCES Schools(ID)
 );
```

and when i insert a student :

```
INSERT INTO Students (s_name , date_birth , school_id )
VALUES ( 'nada' , 2/2/1993 , 1)
```

that error occurs :
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'myschool.dbo.Students'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: Please check if you have INSTEAD OF/AFTER triggers on `Students` table.

Comment: You seem to be be saying ID is the primary key of student and references accounts.id. Is that what you intended? e.g  1 - 1 relationship between Accounts and Students?

Comment: Interesting definition of age. Someone born on 31st December 2011 becomes 1 year old just a day later.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify a value for Students.ID column. You might want to set it as identity, the same you made for Account.ID column:

```
ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: it give me this error : 
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Students__ID__2942188C". The conflict occurred in database "myschool", table "dbo.Accounts", column 'ID'.

Comment: @user3100088: I don't get you. You mean you get the same error?

Comment: no a diffrent error :
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Students__ID__2942188C". The conflict occurred in database "myschool", table "dbo.Accounts"

Comment: @user3100088 This means the value in students.school_Id doesn't exists in Schools table.

Answer (score 1):

Before adding a `Student` you need to find the `ID` of the `Student` from table `Accounts`.

Since `Student` references `Accounts`, these must already exist an `Account` record before a `Student` record can be added, so you might need to begin by adding an Account record first.